# StringTokenizer countTokens() returns 1 with any string

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

Here is my code:

```
StringTokenizer line = new StringTokenizer("{([]{()})({})}");
System.out.println("Count: " + line.countTokens());
```

The output is always `Count: 1`

I know this shouldn't he happening with such a simple code. Could there be something wrong with the `StringTokenizer` library?

Please help!

Comment: Why shouldn't this happen?

Comment: It might help to clear up your misunderstanding of StringTokenizer if you explain why you think that Count: 1 "shouldn't be happening."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default delimiter set of a StringTokenizer includes only whitespace characters, which aren't present in your string.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html#StringTokenizer%28java.lang.String%29

Also note the following statement from the JavaDoc of StringTokenizer:

"StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Didn't know about the whitespace thing. I thought it takes whitespaces as a token as well. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

to print the next token, use System.out.println(line.nextToken());