# countTokens() always returns 1 with user input

Tags: java, input, token, delimiter, stringtokenizer

Before we begin, I don't believe this is a repeat question. I've read the question entitled [StringTokenzer countTokens() returns 1 with any string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27583883/stringtokenizer-counttokens-returns-1-with-any-string/), but that does not address the fact that a properly delimited string is counted correctly, but a properly delimited input is not.

When using the StringTokenizer class I've found that the countTokens method returns different outcomes depending on the whether the argument in countTokens was a defined String or a user defined String. For example, the following code prints the value 4.

```
String phrase = "Alpha bRaVo Charlie delta";

StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
//There's no need to specify the delimiter in the parameters, but I've tried
//both code examples with " " as the delimiter with identical results

int count = token.countTokens();

System.out.println(count);
```

But this code will print the value 1 when the user enters:Alpha bRaVo Charlie delta

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String phrase;

System.out.print("Enter a phrase: ");

phrase = in.next();

StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(phrase);

int count = token.countTokens();

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Just throwong this out there (from the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)): "*StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although **its use is discouraged in new code***". Might wanna consider using `String#split(String)`

Comment: I appreciate the input but I'm required to use the StringTokenizer class for a class Assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  in.nextLine() instead of in.next();

Comment: That won't work. next() and nextLine() both accept String inputs. Just to make sure I tested it out. No change. Using nextLine() also introduces a keyboard buffer problem.

Comment: It is working for me perfectly fine.
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phrase;
        phrase = in.nextLine();
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
        int count = token.countTokens();
        System.out.println(count);

run:
Alpha bRaVo Charlie delta
4
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)

Comment: @CraigK. The difference is that `next()` will break off when it encounters a space. `nextLine()` doesn't

Comment: Beatrice and Vince, thank you for the clarification. The other problems I was having were due to a bugged IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

String phrase;

System.out.print("Enter a phrase: ");

phrase = in.nextLine();

System.out.print(phrase);

StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(phrase);

int count = token.countTokens();

System.out.println(count);

Print phrase and check that in.next() is returning "Alpha".

As suggested above, Use in.nextLine().

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an InputStreamReader, instead of the Scanner:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

String phrase = "";

System.out.print("Enter a phrase: ");

try {
    phrase = in.readLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(phrase);

int count = token.countTokens();

System.out.println(count);
```

nextLine() of Scanner also got the job done for me, though.

If you want the delimiter to be a space-character specifically, you might want to pass it to the constructor of StringTokenizer. It will use " \t\n\r\f" otherwise (which includes the space-character, but might not work as expected if e.g. the \n-character is also present inside the phrase).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the value of `phrase`, after invoking `in.next()`, you will see that's equal to "Alpha". By definition, Scanner's [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) reads the next *token*.

Use `in.nextLine()` instead.

Comment: I've tested your suggestion and now I see the difference between next() and nextLine(), but when I use nextLine() in my specific application, the program doesn't allow the user to input a string and goes right to the end of the program. I suppose I could try a while loop using hasNext and maintain an accumulator.

Comment: I used to have similar problems with reading input using Scanner, due to my IDE. Are you using an IDE? Try running your program on the command line.

Comment: My IDE was indeed buggy, I've since resolved the issue.